# Biblatex is not showing my citations in the drop down list

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have created a .bib file as seen below but when i use the ~\cite{} only 9/19 of my reference appear in the drop down list (using Overleaf). I am not sure why this happening, some work some don't. The ones that do appear in the drop down list work fine. Perhaps there is a synax error I am unaware of, this is my first time using Biblatex.

```
@Misc{DatasheetACS724LLCTR20AU,
  author = {Allegro Microsystems},
  title  = {Automotive-Grade, Galvanically Isolated Current Sensor IC with Common-Mode Field Rejection in a Small-Footprint SOIC8 Package},
}
@Misc{ApplicatioReportGateDrive,
  author = {Lazlo Balogh},
  title  = {Fundamentals of MOSFET and IGBT gate driver circuits}, 
  year = {2017},
}

@Misc{RealTimeSim,
  author = {J. Belanger and J.N. Paquin},
  title  = {The what, where and why of real-time simulation}, 
  year = {2010},
}
@WWW{BoschMobility,
    author  = {Bosch Mobility},
    title   = {Electronic Engine Control Unit},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.bosch-mobility.com/en/solutions/control-units/engine-control-unit/},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}

@Book{FundamentalsOfPowerElectronics,
    author    = {Robert W. Erickson and Dragan Maksimović},
    title     = {Fundamentals of Power Electronics},
    year      = {2007},
    edition   = {2},
    publisher = {Springer New York},
    location  = {New York},
}
@WWW{Opal-rt,
    author  = {opal-RT},
    title   = {Hardware in the Loop. HIL simulation},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.opal-rt.com/hardware-in-the-loop/},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{Electroschematics,
    author  = {T.K. Hareendran},
    title   = {DIY Arduino voltmeter and voltage divider},
    year    = {2023},   
        url     = {https://www.electroschematics.com/arduino-digital-voltmeter/},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{FuseRS,
    author  = {RS Components},
    title   = {A Complete Gide to Fuses},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://uk.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery/ideas-and-advice/fuses-guide},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{HallRS,
    author  = {RS Components},
    title   = {Alles ueber Hall Effekt Sensoren},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://at.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery-portal/produktratgeber/hall-sensoren-leitfaden},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@Misc{SSRApplicationNote,
    author = { Texas Instruments},
    title  = {Isolated Self-Powered AC Solid-State Relay With MOSFETs [Application Note},
        year = {2017},
}

@WWW{Tektronix,
    author  = {Teltronox},
    title   = {Measuring MOSFET Gate Charge with the 4200a-SCS Parameter Analyzer},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.tek.com/en/documents/application-note/measuring-mosfet-gate-charge-4200a-scs-parameter-analyzern},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@Misc{DatasheetRelay,
    author = {Phoenix Contact},
    title  = {Single Relay- REL-MR-24DC/21HC-2961312},
        year = {2019},
}
@WWW{Galco,
    author  = {Galco},
    title   = {Relays - How Relays Work},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.galco.com/comp/relays.htm},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@Article{IsolateGateDrivers,
  author       = {Sanket Sapre},
  title        = {Isolated Gate Drivers—What, Why, and How?},
  journaltitle = {Analog Dialogue},
  year         = {2019},
  volume       = {52},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {1--4},
}
@masterthesis{Thesis,
    author = {H.A.H. van Schaaijk},
    title = {Automatic generation of in-circuit tests on Prodrive's AET system for board assembly defects},
    school = {Eindhoven Univeristy of Technology},
    year = {2017},
}


@WWW{ElectronicsTutorial,
    author  = {W.Storr},
    title   = {MOSFET und Metalloxid-Halbleiter-Tutorial. Basic Electronik},
    year    = {2023},   
        url     = {https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/de/transistoren/mosfet.html},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{CSSElectronics,
    author  = {CSS Electronics},
    title   = {Terminal resistor (120 ohm, DB9, CAN bus},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.csselectronics.com/products/terminal-resistor-can-bus},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@Misc{DatasheetMOSFET,
  author = {Toshiba.},
  title  = {MOSFETs Silicon N-channel MOS TK35A08N1},
  year    = {2012},
}
@WWW{Kvaser,
    author  = {CSS Electronics},
    title   = {Using termination to ensure recessive bit transmission},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://www.kvaser.com/using-termination-ensure-recessive-bit-transmission/},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{ElektorMagazine,
    author  = {C. Valens},
    title   = {How to choose between high-side and low-side switching},
    year    = {2019},   
        url     = {https://www.elektormagazine.com/news/high-side-low-side-switching},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
@WWW{NI,
    author  = {National Insterments},
    title   = {Verwendung von Fehlersimulationseinheiten (fault insertion units, FIUs) für elektroniktests},
    year    = {2023},   
        url     = {https://www.ni.com/de/solutions/transportation/hardware-in-the-loop/using-fault-insertion-units--fius--for-electronic-testing.html},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},          
}

@WWW{OMRON,
    author  = {OMRON},
    title   = {What is an Electrical Relay?},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://components.omron.com/sg-en/products/basic-knowledge/relays/basics},
    urldate = {2021-07-14}, 
}
@WWW{ToshibaBoot,
    author  = {Toshiba},
    title   = {What is the bootstrap circuit in high-voltage IPDS?},
    year    = {},   
        url     = {https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/linear_high-voltage-ipds/high-voltage06.htmls},
    urldate = {2021-07-14},
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is because of using `@www` instead of `@online`. But without knowing, which are not recognized …

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the issue, it is all the WWW ones not working. It was a template I downloaded from my Uni, must be outdated/have errors.

Comment: Such templates are unfortunately often a source of various problems, because no one feels responsible for maintaining them and most users also do not dare to report problems with them.

Comment: Dropbox down menus is something overleaf Provider, not biblatex. So ask their support why it doesnt know the www type.